# SCIM2 => Okta provisioning: Is it possible to update attributes with import?

Tags: okta, okta-api, scim, scim2

When we initially import users into Okta via our SCIM test app, attributes like name and roles are set correctly in Okta. This appears to be configured here in the "To Okta" provisioning settings:

[image: To Okta Provisioning Settings]

With the list of attributes and action to apply here:

[image: Okta Attribute Mappings]

Roles isn't listed here as an attribute, but they are part of the core schema and are imported if supplied by our SCIM app.

It looks like we can only apply these attributes on the initial create? If you edit the various attributes you'll see:

[image: Attribute Settings]

The "Create and update" option is greyed out. So it seems that you can only set attributes with the initial create. Is there some other way to update Okta with changes made in our internal system?

Comment: A similar question was [asked and never answered on the OKTA developer forum](https://devforum.okta.com/t/scim-profile-updates-dont-update-okta-user-profile/14930) perhaps someone who has been through the implementation process on SO can help